# Anthy bar doesn't show up

Tags: keyboard, ibus

I installed all the Anthy ibus packages and changed my Japanese language settings properly but the Anthy bar doesn't show up when I press CTRL+Space. I tried changing the shortcut in the ibus preferences section but it still doesn't work. I have Japanese as my system's default language and up to 2 days ago, Anthy worked just fine (the bar showed up when I pressed CTRL+Space) but then it suddenly stopped working. I tried to uninstall Anthy and installing it again, all to no avail.

What could be the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)